# Python : Read a gzip file and skip header information

Tags: python, python-2.7, gzip

I have a number of zipped text file which i am trying to read using glob(searching the files first) and gzip module. I need to skip the header information from each file. I can do this using a conditional statement at the start of each loop. Is there any better way which i can use to ignore the header information.

My files are like:

```
Name    :abc_201509220101.txt.gzip
Content :
 FILE_TIME|COL1|COL2|COL3|COL4|COL5|COL6|...
 201509201511|1|10|ABC|XXX|AAA|100|...
 201509201512|2|10|ABC|XXX|AAA|100|...
 201509201511|4|10|ABC|XXX|AAA|101|...
 ...
```

I need to skip reading the header note. Any faster approach is welcomed.

CODE:

for file in glob.glob('/*.gz'):
        fh = gzip.open(file,'rb')
        for line in fh:
                if "FILE_TIME" in line:
                        continue

Thanks,

Comment: Please define "faster". Is a 1% speed increase good enough?

Comment: You may also want to show the code you're using, and where you're having problems.

Comment: numpy.loadtxt, numpy.genfromtxt or pandas I/O routines can come in handy; they often have a skipheader keyword. You may just have to wrap the file in a gunzip object of sorts (or there may be an I/O routine that accepts gzipped files by itself).

Comment: when i say faster, i want to avoid using conditional statement each time reading a file. Any attributes that comes along with gzip module which  handles header part ? . Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Why would a gzip module care about the first line(s) in a file?

Comment: Do you files start with `Name     : ....`, or with `FILE_TIME...`? You may want to edit your question to separate file name and contents, if the latter (your code suggests so). It's a bit confusing now what's actually in the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the first line is something you always want to skip, then you can simply `fh.readline()` before the loop. If you need to check that it's actually a header line, then by definition you need a conditional or some equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's

```
seek()
```

function. It is similar to fseek() in C. It takes an offset value and sets the file's current position to the offset.

The important requirement is that you should know the size of the header in bytes.

```
file.seek(size_of_header_in_bytes,0)
```